# Deploying kernel module on customers Linux servers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

As you know if i will try to `insmod` my kernel module on linux server with other linux kernel version there will be error: `could not insert module module.ko: Invalid module format`.
I found only signle solution to compile to compile on each kernel version from sources on customer server, is there a good solution to deploy kernel module for every kernel version without sending source code to customer? Installing every linux distributibe on virtual machine is also not a good solution

Thanks!

Comment: the usual workaround is to create a wrapper that maps specific versions of kernel calls to internal calls inside your module. There you only have to compile your module once, but DO have to compile a version of the wrapper for every kernel version available.

Comment: @MarcB I think that qualifies as an answer :) Why not post it as such?

Comment: @MarcB What about structures? Size and varibales change sometimes

Comment: that'd be something for the wrapper to handle. there's plenty of cases like this: e.g. a wifi firmware blob. closed-source blob with an open-source wrapper around it so it can hook into the kernel.